# Create an image button where the size of button is determine by enclosed image in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to create an image button where width and height of the button to be the same as of those of the image so that all we see is the image not the button. How can i do that?

PS. the reason that I am enclosing an image inside a button is that images are not focus-able I want to focus on an image by pressing tab key, but tab key just skips images

Comment: You can set Focuable=false on Image control instead...

Comment: @Spawn I wan the image to be focused using tab key also there is no such property for image controls in pwf

Comment: My fail, i have read it like "make NOT focusable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image control has Focusable property...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="img1.png" Focusable="True" />
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="img2.png" Focusable="True" />
</Grid>
```

Tab key works great.